# How can I set a background color of a CustomScrollView that contains SilverAppBar and SilverList - in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to get rid of the white part and make it transparent with the background image. I changed the color of the SilverList background to be red in order to make the issue more visible.
Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, I'm new to Flutter and still doesnt understand much and would like to know what am I doing wrong.

[image]

[image]

That's my widget implementation:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            expandedHeight: 275.0,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/background_image.jpeg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              stretchModes: [
                StretchMode.zoomBackground,
                StretchMode.blurBackground,
              ],
            ),
            stretch: true,
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  width: 0,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(48),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(48)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      _buildContainer1(),
                      _buildContainerWithImageAndButton(
                          "assets/barber1.png", "About Us", 241),
                      SizedBox(height: 50),
                      _buildContainerWithImageAndButton(
                          "assets/barber2.png", "Contact", 263),
                      _buildContainer4(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried following some guides and asking GPTchat for assistance because sometimes I do forget some stuff, but unfortunately I wasn't able to find solution, I tried changin the background colors to transparent but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put your background image inside a `Stack` widget instead of inside your `SliverAppBar` because a `CustomScrollView` will layout your slivers side by side (like a  column).

### Code Sample

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/background_image.jpeg',
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            ),
          ),
          CustomScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: <Widget>[
              const SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                expandedHeight: 275.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                elevation: 0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  stretchModes: [
                    StretchMode.zoomBackground,
                    StretchMode.blurBackground,
                  ],
                ),
                stretch: true,
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                  [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      width: 0,
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(48),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(48)),
                      ),
                      // Putting a placeholder here as you didn't provide
                      // _buildContainer & _buildContainerWithImageAndButton
                      child: const Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 5000),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=57ba78f11d725a1c8951eeab50adc43d)

### Result

[image]